# Passing array as option value in wordpress function register_setting

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to pass an array as $option parameter in the register_setting function in Wordpress

```
$settingsArray = array (
    'setting_name_one', 
    'setting_name_two',
    'setting_name_three'
);
foreach ($settingsArray as $setting) {
    register_setting( 'player_row_detail', $setting);
}
```

I have currently achieved:

```
register_setting( 'player_row_detail', 'setting_name_one');
register_setting( 'player_row_detail', 'setting_name_two');
register_setting( 'player_row_detail', 'setting_name_three');
```

Which is the default wordpress usage of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap all of that in a function, and hook into `admin_init`:

```
function register_so_settings() {
    $settingsArray = array (
        'setting_name_one', 
        'setting_name_two',
        'setting_name_three'
    );

    foreach ($settingsArray as $setting) {
        register_setting( 'player_row_detail', $setting);
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_so_settings' );
```

Comment: Worked out fine! Thank you!